# Nginx rewriting pushstate static resources wont load

Tags: nginx, pushstate, react-router

I am trying to get `nginx` to work with a pushstate based uri handled by `react-router`.
Everything works fine until I try to F5 on a second level uri `example.com/MyApp/users`.

My static resources are in `example.com/MyApp/resources`.
The problem is that nginx is trying to load my resources in `example.com/MyApp/users/resources` whenever I try to access directly (or F5) the `users`'s view.

Here is my nginx conf :

```
location ~ ^/MyApp/ {
    try_files $uri /MyApp/index.html last;
}
```

I am new to nginx so I don't really know how everything works...

**EDIT :**

I changed my conf to this:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /MyApp/index.html break;
    }
}
```

Now accessing to `example.com/MyApp/users` works but `example.com/MyApp/users/` doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

With client side app paths:

```
/
/foo
/foo/bar
/foo/bar/baz
/foo/bar/baz/123
/tacos
/tacos/123
```

Use nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/example.com;

    gzip_static on;

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    # Attempt to load static files, if not found route to @rootfiles
    location ~ (.+)\.(html|json|txt|js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|svg|ico|eot|otf|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {
      try_files $uri @rootfiles;
    }

    # Check for app route "directories" in the request uri and strip "directories"
    # from request, loading paths relative to root.
    location @rootfiles {
      rewrite ^/(?:foo/bar/baz|foo/bar|foo|tacos)/(.*) /$1 redirect;
    }
}
```

This configuration will work within a pushState "directory" such as `example.com/foo/bar/baz/213123` and resolve static files at relative paths like `js/app.js` to `example.com/js/app.js` instead of `example.com/foo/bar/baz/js/app.js`.

For cases with directory depth beyond the first level such as `/foo/bar/baz`, note the order of the directories declared in the @rootfiles directive: the longest possible paths need to go first, followed by the next shallower path `/foo/bar` and finally `/foo`.

[See this related answer to a similar question regarding Backbone.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30515169/1774183)

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to do something like this:

```
location ~ ^/MyApp/ {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
location ~ ^/MyApp/resources {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri/ /resources/index.html =404;
}
```