# PageJs pretty URLs in Polymer aren't working

Tags: routes, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

I'm having some difficulties to use pretty Urls in my application which is Polymer 100% app and powered by Firebase. It's based on Polymer Starter Kit 1.2.0.

I'm wanting to access the route `localhost:5000/user/edit`. If I'm in the home page (localhost:5000) and click in a button with a `href="/user/edit"` it works fine. But, if I refresh the page of if I go directly to the `"/user/edit"` route without passing by the home page, appears a lot of problems related to find the files. The console shows the following:

```
edit:36 GET http://localhost:5000/user/styles/main.css  edit:37 GET
http://localhost:5000/user/styles/pikaday.css  edit:41 GET
http://localhost:5000/user/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js
edit:45 GET http://localhost:5000/user/elements/elements.html 404 (Not
Found)
```

My **app.js** file has only these lines:

```
var app = document.querySelector('#app');
app.baseUrl = '/';
```

And my **routing.html** is:

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

// Removes end / from app.baseUrl which page.base requires for production
if (window.location.port === '') {  // if production
  page.base(app.baseUrl.replace(/\/$/, ''));
}

// Routes
page('/', function() {
  app.route = 'home';
});

page(app.baseUrl, function() {
  app.route = 'home';
});

page('/user/edit', function() {
  app.route = 'user/edit';
});

page('*', function() {
  console.info('404 page');
  page.redirect(app.baseUrl);
});

// add #! before urls
page({
  hashbang: false
});
});
</script>
```

I tried a lot of things:

- If I change the route `/user/edit` to `user-edit`, it works fine.
  Apparently the problem is related to the '/' in the route.
- If I set hashbang to true, it also works fine. But, I'm really wanting to work pretty URLs in my application.
- If in the index.html I change `<link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">` to `<link rel="import" href="/elements/elements.html">` the browser finds all the elements, but routing continues with the same problem.

Any ideas about how to solve this problem? I believe that it will help a lot of people who also wants to work with pretty URLs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the problem! There's a important detail in the documentation about using firebase pretty URLs that was missing in the documentation.

According to the documentation: https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/deploy-to-firebase-pretty-urls.md

There's a important step:
`7. Add <base href="/"> to head in index.html`

But, the detail is that the tag `<base href="/">` should be added in the begging of the `head` and before the others imports. The problem is that I had put this in the end of the `<head>`, so I just put it in the beginning and started working fine.

After wasting a lot of time with this detail, I made a suggestion to the Polymer Startet Kit to improve the doc: https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/670

Hope this doubt will help more people :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a server-side problem. Basically, you'll have to enable support for HTML5's `pushstate` on your server. If you are using apache, you can edit your `.htaccess` file like [this one](https://gist.github.com/rayfranco/3211654). For Nginx, you can refer to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9194149/4915561).

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help! :)

I'm using `firebase hosting` and there is a guide to use pretty urls on it: https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/deploy-to-firebase-pretty-urls.md. Seems the guide already tells about using `rewrites` to solve the problem you commented.

But, I already applied this guide even before asking here and stills not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with app or router page.js. Because when you click on button, uri `/user/edit` add to your host `localhost:5000`. But when you reload a page, the host is disappear. First, delete this section and try again:

```
page(app.baseUrl, function() {
  app.route = 'home';
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping! I deleted the section above and tried again. The problem continued the same :(

Comment: You modify the file  `page.js` in source? And why use this: `// Removes end / from app.baseUrl which page.base requires for production
if (window.location.port === '') {  // if production
  page.base(app.baseUrl.replace(/\/$/, ''));
}` It's must be used in `app.js`, not in the router.

Comment: This part already came in the `Polymer Starter Kit`: https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/app/scripts/app.js. I didn't modify page.js in source

Comment: Check routing [sourсe](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/app/elements/routing.html). In example first path is star `page('star', scrollToTop, closeDrawer, function(ctx, next) {
      next();
    });`

Comment: Hey @Dmitry, thanks for trying to help me. I just solved the problem, it was a `tag` misplaced on the end of `<head>` that should be in the beggining. I posted the answer explaining. Thanks bro :)